# Convergence of Random Series in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables in $L^2$. Let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + x_n$ and write 
$$\mu_n = \mathbb{E}[S_n], \sigma_n^2 = var(S_n)$$
Show that b) implies a) where,

a) the sequences $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n^2$ converge in $\mathbb{R}$

b) there exists a RV S such that $S_n \rightarrow S$ a.s. and in $L^2$

I am struggling to show that $\sigma_n^2$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\sigma_n^2 = \mathbb{E}[S_n^2] - \mathbb{E}[S_n]^2$. Since $S_n \to S$ in $L^2$ we also have that $\mathbb{E}[S_n^2] \to \mathbb{E}[S^2]$ as $n \to \infty$. Additionally, $\mathbb{E}[S_n] \to \mathbb{E}[S]$ since by Holder's inequality, $|\mathbb{E}[S_n - S]| \leq \|S_n- S\|_{L^2}$. In particular, $\sigma_n^2 \to \mathbb{E}[S^2] - \mathbb{E}[S_n]^2 = \operatorname{Var}(S)$.

Comment: Why do we have that $\mathbb{E}[S_n^2] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[S^2]$? We only have that $\mathbb{E}[(S_n-S)^2] \rightarrow 0$

Comment: In any normed space, if $\|x_n - x \| \to 0$ then $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$. This is a standard consequence of the reverse triangle inequality since $|\|x_n\| - \|x\|| \leq \|x_n - x\| \to 0$. Now apply that to the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: It is a simple proof that a implies b ($L^p$ martingale convergence). In my proof above, I have only used $L^2$ convergence (I think), but then this gives me $L^2$ convergence implies a.s. convergence in this case, is this true?

Comment: For Martingales it is indeed true that $L^2$ convergence implies a.s. convergence. Almost Sure convergence is one of the things provided by the martingale convergence theorem and $L^2$ convergence implies the hypotheses of that theorem so that $L^2$ convergence of a martingale implies almost sure convergence.